RecyclerView item selection issue after filtering
I'm encountering an issue with item selection in a RecyclerView after applying filtering. Here's the scenario:
I have a RecyclerView displaying a list of items using a custom adapter (PayloadAdapter). The adapter provides filtering functionality based on the server name. However, after filtering the list and selecting an item, the selection doesn't correspond to the correct item in the original unfiltered list.
For example, if I filter the list and select the first item in the filtered list, it chooses the first item in the default unfiltered list, and the same applies to selecting the second, third, and subsequent items.
I suspect the issue lies in how I'm handling item selection after filtering the list. How can I ensure that item selection corresponds to the correct item in the original unfiltered list?
PayloadAdapter class:
public class PayloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PayloadAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private final List<PayloadModel> payloadList;
    public SimpleDraweeView selectedSImage;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private final List<PayloadModel> payloadListFiltered;


    public PayloadAdapter(List<PayloadModel> payloadList) {
        this.payloadList = payloadList;
        this.payloadListFiltered = payloadList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PayloadModel payload = payloadList.get(position);
        holder.bind(payload);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return payloadList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String query = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                List<PayloadModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    filteredList.addAll(payloadList);
                } else {
                    for (PayloadModel payload : payloadList) {
                        if (payload.getServerName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                            filteredList.add(payload);
                        }
                    }
                }
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredList;
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                payloadListFiltered.clear();
                payloadListFiltered.addAll((List<PayloadModel>) filterResults.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    private void loadPayloadIcon() {
            neth("ze");
    }

    public void neth(String pogiko) {

        String flagUrl = "" + pogiko + ".webp";


        selectedSImage.setImageURI(flagUrl);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameTextView, infoTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNamea);
            infoTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sinf);
            selectedSImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImagea);
        }

        public void bind(PayloadModel payload) {
            nameTextView.setText(payload.getServerName());
            infoTextView.setText(payload.getPayloadInfo());
            loadPayloadIcon();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


}

PayloadActivity
public class PayloadActivity extends BaseActivity implements PayloadAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    EditText editTextSearch;
    private wamp config;
    private Settings mConfig;
    private List<PayloadModel> payloadList;
    private PayloadAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.server);

        final EditText editTextSearch = findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
        
        
        
        payloadList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new PayloadAdapter(payloadList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        loadPayloadData();


        editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }

I tried adjusting the click listener in the ViewHolder class to retrieve the correct item from the original list (payloadList) instead of using the position from the filtered list (payloadListFiltered).
Specifically, I modified the onClick method in the ViewHolder class to use payloadList.get(getAdapterPosition()) to retrieve the correct item from the original list and pass its position to the listener.
What I expected was that by retrieving the item from the original list, the selected item would correspond to the correct item in the unfiltered list, regardless of filtering.

Probably the error is that in the onBindViewHolder method you take models of an unfiltered list:
PayloadModel payload = payloadList.get(position);

Try:
PayloadModel payload = payloadListFiltered.get(position);


This didnt work, same effect as before
